# Three.js 3D Cube rotation on axis

Tags: javascript, 3d, rotation, three.js, webgl

I currently have a cube that I'm trying to rotate on a corner. I need it to spin on the corner like the photo below.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/fiu/2198328580/

I'm new to Three.js, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

Here's the code for what I currently have

```
var geometry= new THREE.CubeGeometry (200,200,200, 4, 4, 4);
             // material

            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('inc/cube.jpg'), overdraw: true
             }); 



            cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            cube.overdraw = true;
            cube.position.y = 80;
            cube.position.x = 5;
            cube.position.z = 6;
            cube.rotation.z = 14.9;
            cube.rotation.y = 0 ;
            cube.rotation.x = 0 ;


            scene.add(cube);
```

On another note.... since I have the cube.jpg texture on the cube, if I have the values for the THREE.CubeGeometry set to (200,200,200) without the 4's, the texture warps... Anyone know how to stop the warping?

This is what I'm using to render:

`renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setClearColorHex(0xffffff, 0);
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ); container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );`

It seems to work across most browsers, but if I use the WebGL renderer, it gives me issues with the Opacity of the Canvas.

To see the Project as it stands right now, its at http://fiudevspace.com/spincube

Comment: Have you tried with WebGLRenderer({antialias: true}) ?

Comment: Tried it, but it still gives me an issue with the opacity... would I need to change anything about the .setClearColorHex in order for it to work?

Comment: You can also try to change color, ambient & etc properties of MeshLambertMaterial

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DaveBenRoberts/3bCuH/#&togetherjs=u15aaJASAr

Comment: Have you used TrackballControls.js? Position the mesh as your wish and disable pan and zoom controls. Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually all you need is to rotate the cube 45 degrees on a different axis from the 45 degrees you have already rotated - I do not use THREE as it would get between me and my solution more than it helps - remember the rule of thumb on object rotations :  first translate the center of the object back to the origin (if not already there) then rotate about each axis you need, then finally translate the object back into position (reverse of previous translation) - hope this helps